# Enabling Paste via keyboard shortcut in Swift UI for Mac OS

Tags: macos, swiftui, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard, copy-paste

I have a simple Mac App written in SwiftUI which retrieves network data. In the login screen (and throughout the app) I am able to Paste via: Right-Click/Select - Paste
but not via the keyboard shortcut: Command/V

```
var body: some View {    
 
    VStack {

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.fixed(170)), GridItem(.fixed(300))]) {

                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Label("server", systemImage: "globe")
                }
                
                TextField("server", text: $server)
                    .padding()
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Label("user", systemImage: "person")
                }
                
                TextField("user", text: $user)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .padding()
                
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Label("password", systemImage: "ellipsis.rectangle")
                }
                
                SecureField("password", text: $password)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
```

I tried looking in the Edit menu, but it only shows: Start Dictation, Emojis and Symbols.

So, I am assuming that the edit menu is somehow not fully enabled.

Could anyone advise what I need to do to turn this on?

Comment: Maybe you override those commands somewhere else? What is in your App struct?

Comment: YES! That's it. I'd totally forgotten that I'd added some code ages ago in App struct to hide some of the menus that were not needed. For some unknown reason - probably copying from another app - I'd included Pasteboard.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe you override those commands somewhere else? What is in your App struct?

The suggestion from @soundflix is correct. I'd disabled this option myself in the main App struct by adding:

```
CommandGroup(replacing: .pasteboard) { }
```